# spring inject unmarshalled xml

Tags: java, spring, jaxb2

In my standalone application I need to read a bunch of xml files and convert them to java object.
Here is my applicationContext.xml

```
...
<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>....</list>
...
```

I'm able to convert xml with the code

```
@Autowired
private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
public void myMethod(String file){
    Context c = (Context) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(file)));
}
```

I was wondering if is possible to unmarshall the xml in applicationContext and then autowire them where necessary. Is it?

By now for convert all xml files I need to call "myMethod" several times.
What is the best practice?